# Two definitions of vectors and general spinor transformations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vectors, definition, spinors

The usual definition of a vector is that its components transform contravariantly under the change of coordinate chart on the underlying manifold -- it is an element of the tangent bundle of the (let's say) Minkowski spacetime.

Recently, I have seen a different definition in some QFT textbooks (eg. A Modern Introduction to QFT by Maggiore), that is, that vector is an element of the Lorentz group (1/2, 1/2)-representation space.

1. Doesnt this enlarge the space of possible vectors and tensors as compared to the usual definition? (eg. levi-civita symbol might be considered a (pseudo-)tensor as the transformation rule is only imposed under (proper) Lorentz transformations...)
2. If this is only a notation simplification used in QFT on Minkowski spacetime beacuse why only use inertial frames -- why arent we interested in non-inertial frames such as constantly accelerating (and Rindler transformations)?
3. Even if really in QFT is onky concerned with inertial observers, all objects should be subjected to some transformation rule under passive transformation. Even between cartesian and spherical coordinates of the space. What is such a general transformation rule for spinors (say belonging to the (1/2, 0) Lorentz group representation)?